# How to recursively go through an array of ojects with child arrays and return a final transformed array of objects

Tags: recursion, transformation, reduce

I am looking to loop over an object that can also have arrays of objects that can have arrays of objects, and so on. In theory this structure could be infinite, but it would be very unlikely to ever be more than 12 layers deep this way.

example of data structure before transform:

```
{
  id: '1234',
  name: 'item 1',
  children: [
    {
      id: '2345',
      name: 'item 2',
      // other properties that I don't care about will be here too
      children: [
        {
          id: '3456',
          name: 'item 3',
          children: [
            {
              id: '4567',
              name: 'item 4',
            }
          ],
        }
      ],
    }
  ],
}
```

what I need the final data structure to look like (need a default first object):

```
const someArray = [
  {
    // this first child is static and will always be here after transform
    title: 'Projects'
    key: 'projects',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'item 1', // this is 'name' property
        key: '1234,' // this is 'id' property
        children: [
          {
            title: 'item 2',
             key: '2345',
             children: [
               // continue as long as there are children arrays
             ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried a few different solutions and I believe that a recursive function is the solution to this, but I am just not able to figure out how to output the final structure. I get the last two children, but I am unable to accumulate the previous children.

This is the non-working solution I have gotten the closest with:

```
const startingObj = [ 
  {
    title: 'Projects',
    key: 'projects',
  }
]

function buildTree (obj) {
  // check if we have a children array with at least 1 child.
  if (obj?.children?.length) {
    return obj?.children.reduce((a, item) => {
      if (a) return {
        ...item.children,
        title: a.name || a.title,
        key: a.id || a.key,
      };
      if (item?.children?.length) return buildTree(item.children);
    }, obj);
  }
}

buildTree(); // would pass in the sample data structure from above here.
```

I am not sure if maybe a reduce is not the best solution here or I am just missing some key idea from my approach. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
// this function recurses down the tree and for each item it makes a
// transformed item (saving only the title and key). Then the transformed
// item is returned and the caller pushes it into the children array
function buildtree(obj) {
  let item = {
    title: obj.name || obj.title,
    key: obj.id || obj.key,
    children: []
  }

  if (obj.children)
    for (child of obj.children)
      item.children.push( buildtree(child) )

  return item;
}

let result = [ 
  {
    title: 'Projects',
    key: 'projects',
    children: []
  }
]

result[0].children.push( buildtree(obj) )
```

Here is a full runnable example:

```
obj = {
  id: '1234',
  name: 'item 1',
  x: '', // other properties that I don't care about will be here too
  children: [
    {
      id: '2345',
      name: 'item 2',
      x: '', // other properties that I don't care about will be here too
      children: [
        {
          id: '3456',
          name: 'item 3',
          x: '', // other properties that I don't care about will be here too
          children: [
            {
              id: '4567',
              name: 'item 4',
              x: '', // other properties that I don't care about will be here too
            },
            {
              id: '5678',
              name: 'item 5',
              x: '', // other properties that I don't care about will be here too
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: '6789',
          name: 'item 6',
          x: '', // other properties that I don't care about will be here too
          children: [
            {
              id: '7890',
              name: 'item 7',
              x: '', // other properties that I don't care about will be here too
            },
            {
              id: '890a',
              name: 'item 8',
              x: '', // other properties that I don't care about will be here too
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: '90ab',
      name: 'item 9',
      x: '', // other properties that I don't care about will be here too
      children: [
        {
          id: '0abc',
          name: 'item 10',
          x: '', // other properties that I don't care about will be here too
          children: [
            {
              id: 'abcd',
              name: 'item 11',
              x: '', // other properties that I don't care about will be here too
            },
            {
              id: 'bcde',
              name: 'item 12',
              x: '', // other properties that I don't care about will be here too
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 'cdef',
          name: 'item 13',
          x: '', // other properties that I don't care about will be here too
          children: [
            {
              id: 'defg',
              name: 'item 14',
              x: '', // other properties that I don't care about will be here too
            },
            {
              id: 'efgh',
              name: 'item 15',
              x: '', // other properties that I don't care about will be here too
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

console.log( JSON.stringify(obj) )

function buildtree(obj) {
  let item = {
    title: obj.name || obj.title,
    key: obj.id || obj.key,
    children: []
  }

  if (obj.children)
    for (child of obj.children)
      item.children.push( buildtree(child) )

  return item;
}

let result = [ 
  {
    title: 'Projects',
    key: 'projects',
    children: []
  }
]
result[0].children.push( buildtree(obj) )

console.log( JSON.stringify(result) )
```

Comment: It wasn't recursion, but this does work much better for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Phorden When you say "It wasn't recursion" that means I misunderstood what you were trying to do.  How was what you were trying to do different from what I did?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't exactly what I meant. What I meant was that I wasn't thinking that I should need to push to an array (instead of returning a whole new array), but the solution still works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, if I have you right, you just need to iterate over all the objects and for each one change the 'id' key to 'key' and the 'name' key to 'title'. Here is a recursive solution:

```
function recursiveArray(arr) {
  return arr.map(e => ({
    key: e.id,
    title: e.name,
    children: e.children.length ? recursiveArray(e.children) : []
  }));
}

function changeKeysOfNestedObject(obj) {
  return {
    key: obj.id, 
    title: obj.name,
    children: obj.children.length ? recursiveArray(obj.children) : []
  };
}

//test case
console.log(changeKeysOfNestedObject({
  id: '1234',
  name: 'item 1',
  children: [
    {
      id: '2345',
      name: 'item 2',
      children: [
        {
          id: '3456',
          name: 'item 3',
          children: [
            {
              id: '4567',
              name: 'item 4',
              children: []
            }
          ],
        }
      ],
    }
  ],
}));
```